# Application is not shown in browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xampp

I am just starting with Ruby on Rails, because I was told that it is a powerful framework to build web applications.
Maybe it is true, but I can not test it (yet).
My problem is that even if in the tutorials everything seem to be clear and easy, I think I am missing steps during configuration.
I have a xampp1.7.4 server running on my Ubuntu10.10 system, which is loocated in

```
/opt/lampp
```

Then, following this [tutorial](http://rails.homelinux.org/) or any other, I made the first step:

```
rails myProyect
```

It generates a new folder with a structure of a RoR project. Then I paste that folder on /opt/lampp/htdocs and just going to http://localhost/myProject/ it should appear the RoR welcome message, but instead I am getting the tree of the folder, as the image attached shows.

[image: Application on browser]

Can anybody help me to figure out what I have missed?? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use rails on apache, you should look into http://www.modrails.com/
And if you want to test your first rails application just go to the app directory and start WEBrick (simple http server):

```
cd /opt/lampp/htdocs/myProject
rails server
```

Comment: this is correct, you should just use the rails server or rails s command for development.

Comment: Thank you for the link. But with your command, it just generates another project named server

Comment: what version of rails are you running? `rails -v` if it's < 3 you should use `ruby srcipt/server` instead of `rails server`

Comment: I am using 2.3.5. Thank you so much!!

Comment: Now I have this problem   Status: 500 Internal Server Error
  Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
Maybe you know where to change the path to mysqld.sock?? in my.cnd is already changed, and I have mysql running with no problem on my computer. Thanks

Comment: add to the `config/database.yml` socket option: `socket: /path/to/mysqld.sock`